# rails, why is my page redirecting after onchange event handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, event-handling

I am little confused why this is happening

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-padding-helper">
      <%= form_tag product_builder_path, method: :get, remote: true, class: 'product_builder_form' do %>
      <div>
        <%= label_tag :banner_top, "Banner", class: "label-style" %>
        <%= select_tag :banner_top, options_from_collection_for_select(BannerTemplate.where(user_id: [1,current_user.id]).collect {|p| p}, 'id', 'name', params[:banner_top].to_i), class:'form-control banner-top-select', data: { remote: true }, onchange: "this.form.submit();" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-padding-helper">
        <%= label_tag 'Campaign Size' %></br>
        <%= select_tag 'type', options_for_select(['Small (4 Products)', 'Medium (7 Products)', 'Large (10 Products)' ], params[:type]), multiple: false, class: "form-control product-builder-",  data: { remote: true }, onchange: "this.form.submit();"  %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-padding-helper">
        <%= label_tag 'Theme' %></br>
        <%= select_tag 'theme', options_for_select(['Default BWX Theme', 'Black Friday Theme'], params[:theme]), multiple: false, class: "form-control", onchange: "this.form.submit();" %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Unless I have respond_to block in my controller, my assumption is that when I select something it shouldn't redirect but in fact it is redirecting. Can someone explain why this is happening?

This is from my console:

```
Started GET "/product_builder?utf8=%E2%9C%93&banner_top=60&type=Medium+%287+Products%29&theme=Default+BWX+Theme&banner_top=69" for ::1 at 2018-02-15 15:21:09 -0800
Processing by CampaignsController#product_builder as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "banner_top"=>"69", "type"=>"Medium (7 Products)", "theme"=>"Default BWX Theme"}

Started GET "/product_builder?utf8=%E2%9C%93&banner_top=69&type=Medium+%287+Products%29&theme=Default+BWX+Theme" for ::1 at 2018-02-15 15:21:10 -0800
Processing by CampaignsController#product_builder as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "banner_top"=>"69", "type"=>"Medium (7 Products)", "theme"=>"Default BWX Theme"}
```

So, right after it is processed by JS, it is followed by HTML. What am I doing wrong here?

thank you

Comment: You need a file named `product_builder.js.erb`, requesting as JS and file not exist it returns to html template. Create `filename.js.erb` file and let me know...

Comment: Can you change your log level to :Info or :debug and repost your server's output?

Comment: @7urkm3n if you change to remote it shouldn't do anything no? if you add a link_to tag with a remote: true option and click it unless you set something it won't redirect or render. In the console you will only have processed by JS not both JS and HTML

Comment: @AnthonyL not much difference when i change the log level to :info or :debug...

Comment: @mike, why not post controller methods also ?